# How to prevent read() method from splitting based on delimiter inside quotation marks in csv?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-csv

For example, if I have something like

"I like, cookies"

I do NOT want Spark's `read()` to csv method to split between the *like* and *cookies*. I want it to be parsed as *"I like, cookies"*. I thought this was common csv practice, but this is being separated.

I saw similar questions mentioned using Databricks but I am trying to avoid that. Is there any other way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: The delimiter is a comma so I do not want a delimiter inside quotation marks to separate.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are using csv reader ?

Comment: I get that. Can u show what options have u tried so far and also with some more sample data if you have.